# Apache retain file name and extension

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to configure aliases for static files in apache. My config looks something like:

```
Alias "/x760yxl1" "/home/soft/public/user_12/pa01.mp4"
Alias "/y460yzl5" "/home/soft/public/user_21/pa05.mp4"
```

When navigating to the *x760yxl1* route, the browser downloads the file with the name provided in the alias (*x760yxl1*, without the *.mp4*). How do I make apache serve the file, retaining the original name and extension (*pa01.mp4* & *pa05.mp4*)? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question (jic anybody finds this helpful). After taking some time to read the apache docs, I've solved this by just replacing the *Alias* directive with *Redirect*, which now serves the file in its original form ️